# C# Returning an enum and an int array

Tags: c#, enums

I'm working on something where I would need to return an enum and an array of ints. I can go around the whole issue and use an int instead of the enum and add it as the first element of the array, but the enum really helps my code legibility. Is there any way to return both at the same time?

Comment: The answer gives reasonable options, but I can't help but think that there's a larger design problem to solve here. Can you describe what the method is doing, that it is returning a mutable collection of integers and an enumerated type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 common solutions to this. 
Which one is appropriate would depend on the specific situation and your personal preference:

1. Use an `out` parameter for one of them. This doesn't require any new types, but is inconvenient to call. Additionally, it may not semantically capture the relationship between the returned values.

   ```
   public int[] MyMethod(out MyEnumType myEnum)
   { 
       myEnum = ...
       int[] nums = ...    
       return nums;
   }
   ```
2. Use the [`Tuple<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) type (.NET 4.0). This only requires the construction of a closed generic-type from an existing BCL type, but callers may not like the fact that the encapsulated properties have meaningless names:  `Item1` and `Item2` You can also the `KeyValuePair<,>` type or write your own `Pair<,>` type to serve a similar purpose.

   ```
   public Tuple<int[], MyEnumType> MyMethod() 
   {
       int[] nums = ...
       MyEnumType myEnum = ...
       return Tuple.Create(nums, myEnum); 
   }
   ```
3. Write a wrapper class that encapsulates the int array and the enum. More work, but nicest to work with for the caller.

   ```
   public class Wrapper
   { 
       public int[] Nums { get { ... } } 
       public MyEnumType MyEnum { get { ... } }
   }
   ...
   public Wrapper MyMethod() 
   { 
       Wrapper wrapper = ...
       return wrapper;
   }
   ```

Comment: I thought of using a wrapper class. Didn't know C# has tuples so I guess that'd be the way to go. Do you know if there is any performance impact over sticking to int of using Tuples?

Comment: @user472875: Wrapper class would really be the way to go, if the two have a logical meaning together.

Comment: @user472875: There shouldn't be; it's really lightweight. If you're interested, you can use a decompiler to look at its source. As with any other performance issues, use a profiler to identify that the problem is actually in the construction of the wrapper (custom or tuple), and then profile each alternative.